# How to find and remove spy software on phone

Tags: malware, whatsapp-messenger, resource-monitoring

My girlfriend has an admirer which started out as a good friend. He confessed his love for her some time ago and started to become more and more aggressive while being rejected. He recently started to show some stalker like behavior and started to appear near her flat at late nighttime.

He also hinted, that he always knew when she was chatting with me through WhatsApp. I'm therefore afraid that he might have installed some Spyware on her Android-Phone (HTC One X+)

Is there a way to identify Whatsapp Spyware and to remove it?

Comment: The long and short! *Go and report it to your local law enforcement authorities.*

Comment: BTW Relevant [linky](http://www.zdnet.com/whatsapp-still-breaching-privacy-laws-canadian-dutch-probe-7000010452/) about Whatsapp, in plain and short, don't use it! :) There was a recent report about it sending IMEI numbers in the clear...

Answer (score 1):

Format the sd card and flash the stock rom again. This would guarantee clearing out any spyware. Here is a [tutorial](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1859714) describing how to take it back to stock.

"…I say we take off and nuke the entire site from orbit. It’s the only way to be sure."

Answer (score 1):

I'd **suspect** that there's no spyware on her phone. Whatsapp shows when a contact is online or has last been online, so it's possible that the person assumes that when she's online, she's chatting with you. You can prevent this by opening Whatsapp and going to `Menu -> Settings -> Contacts -> Blocked contacts` and adding the stalker to the block list on her Whatsapp account. This should prevent him from seeing her Whatsapp activity.

Otherwise, designerWhoCodes's answer is the only certain way of removing spyware.